# SQL percent finding task

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to get percents of processing errors for each type of messages.
By the way we need only take percents which are > 5%.
Tried to find solutions, but nothing works..

The Structure of Database:

[image: The Structure of Database]

**QRY_TYPE** (`ID` – unique identifier of type, `С_NAME` – name of type, `C_AB_REF` – link to the abonent, who processes these types of messages).

**ST_ABONENTS** (`ID` – unique identifier, `С_NAME` – name)

**QRY_QUEUE** (`ID` – unique identifier, `С_IN_TIME` – date and time of writing msg into table, `C_EXEC_TIME` – date and time of the msg processing, `C_ST` – processing status (null - didn't, 1 – successfull, 0 – error with processing), `C_QRY_TYPE` – link for the query type).

Thats one of my tries, its still doesnt work

```
select qt.c_name as qrytype, count(qq.C_ST)/(SELECT count(*) from qry_queue)*100 as PRC
from qry_type qt 
inner join qry_queue qq on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
where qq.c_st =0 
group by qt.c_name;
```

Result should looks like this

[image: RESULT]

Comment: You seem to use Oracle (`VarChar2`), why do you tag `mysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without actual data and info what exactly *doesnt work*.

So this might be what you want:

```
select *
from
 (
   select qt.c_name as qrytype, 
      count(case when qq.c_st = '0' then qq.C_ST end) -- only rows with errors
      /count(*) * 100 as  PRC                         -- all rows
   from qry_type qt 
   inner join qry_queue qq on qt.id = qq.c_qry_type
   group by qt.c_name
 ) dt
where PRC >= 5
```